# Problem with view the open port of openssh-server

Tags: 12.10, vmware

I have a problem when trying to view the open port of `openssh-server` from the command:
`sudo netstat -anp -tcp`

**Image:** 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/mxzpUtO.png]

Any idea how to fix this? Or view the port from OpenSSH server?

Note: I'm using VMWare Workstation 10, and using `ubuntu-12.10-server-i386` from classroom jobs. And in other virtual machines the command works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question: Ubuntu 12.10 is outdated and not supported anymore. You should update.

`sudo` complains that is can not resolve your hostname (`ubuntuSv28`). In order to fix the warning quickly, add the hostname to youe `/etc/hosts` file with a line like:

```
127.0.1.1   ubuntuSv28
```

A good command line for seeing the listening ports would be:

```
sudo netstat -nlpt
```

And BTW: The port for OpenSSH is 22.